# Nodejs:express-winston logging issue

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-dynamodb, winston

I am using `express-winston` and `winston-dynamodb` in order to store the http request and response into dynamodb.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-dynamodb

Here is the schema of the table

```
-hostname
-id
-level(partition key)
-meta (the request and response detail will be stored here)
-msg
-timestamp(sort key)
```

It is successful to store the data into dynamodb but the format is not satisfactory
Is it possible to store the data with below format?

```
{
"id" : ObjectId("5a12537d81b6b634cb7d4696"),
"timestamp" : ISODate("2017-11-20T04:01:01.229Z"),
"level" : "info",
"status": 200,
"requestUrl": '/',
"meta" : {}
}
```

Similar as below SO question but I am using dynamodb instead of mongodb
[Logging with winston-mongodb, express-winston and winston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47385078/logging-with-winston-mongodb-express-winston-and-winston)

winston-logger.js

```
const winston = require('winston');
const { DynamoDB } = require('winston-dynamodb');
const expressWinston = require('express-winston');

const logger = expressWinston.logger({
  transports: [
    new DynamoDB({
      accessKeyId: "accessKey",
      secretAccessKey: "secretKey",
      region: "myRegion",
      tableName: "test"
    })
  ],
  format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.colorize(),
    winston.format.timestamp(),
    winston.format.json()
  ),
  metaField: null,
  expressFormat: true,
  requestWhitelist: ['headers', 'body', 'query'],
  responseWhitelist: [,'body'],
})

module.exports = logger
```

app.js

```
const winstonLogger = require('./winston-logger');
app.use(winstonLogger)
```